# Dask: DataFrame taking forever to compute

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I created a Dask dataframe from a Pandas dataframe that is ~50K rows and 5 columns:

```
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=32)
```

I then add a bunch of columns (~30) to the dataframe and try to turn it back into a Pandas dataframe:

```
DATA = ddf.compute(get = dask.multiprocessing.get)
```

I looked at the docs and if I don't specify `num_workers`, it defaults to using all my cores.  I'm on a 64 core EC2 instance and the above line has taken minutes already without finishing...

Any idea how to speed up or what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the default threaded scheduler?  How do you add your new columns?  Any chance you can provide a more complete example?  

http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduler-choice.html

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to try lowering the amount of threads and increasing the amount of processes to help speed up things.

Comment: can you give an example/guide how to do that?

Comment: I found this documentation very helpful:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-efficiently-parallelize-dask-dataframe-computation-on-a-single-machine-1f10b5b02177